# Node error: E11000 duplicate key error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am attempting to create a record for a "family" object using Mongoose in an Express route. I am getting this error on the SECOND attempt to create a family:

```
{ BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error index: treemaker.families.$members.parents.id_1 dup key: { : null }
```

I am unsure what this means. Here is the full route. Mongoose seems to get tripped up at the very end:

```
router.post('/', jwtAuth, jsonParser, (req, res) => {

    // checking that given id is valid
    let { family_name, password, username, id } = req.body; 

    User.findOne({ _id: id})
        .count()
        .then(count => {
            if (count < 1) {
                return Promise.reject({
                    code: 422, 
                    reason: 'Validation Error', 
                    message: 'Family must be created by a user', 
                    location: 'id'
                })
            } 
            return Promise.resolve();  
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return res.sendStatus(422).json({code: err.code, message: err.message, reason: err.reason, location: err.location })
        }); 

    // checking that required fields are present

    const requiredFields = ['family_name', 'username', 'password']; 
    const missingField = requiredFields.find(field => !(field in req.body)); 

    if(missingField) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            code: 422, 
            reason: 'Validation Error', 
            message: 'Missing field', 
            location: missingField
        }); 
    }

    // checking the format of string fields 

    const stringFields = ['family_name', 'password', 'username']; 
    const nonStringField = stringFields.find(
        field => field in req.body && typeof req.body[field] !== 'string'
    ); 

    if (nonStringField) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            code: 422, 
            reason: 'Validation Error', 
            message: 'Incorrect field type: expected string', 
            location: nonStringField
        }); 
    }

    // checking the trimming on fields 

    const trimmedFields = ['family_name', 'password', 'username']; 
    const nonTrimmedField = trimmedFields.find(
        field => req.body[field].trim() !== req.body[field]
    ); 

    if (nonTrimmedField) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            code: 422, 
            reason: 'Validation Error', 
            message: 'Cannot start or end with whitespace', 
            location: nonTrimmedField
        }); 
    }

    // checking the length of fields 

    const sizedFields = {
        family_name: { min: 1 }, 
        password: { min: 10, max: 72 }, 
        username: { min: 10, max: 72 }
    }; 

    const tooSmallField = Object.keys(sizedFields).find(field => 
        'min' in sizedFields[field] && 
        req.body[field].trim().length < sizedFields[field].min
    )

    const tooLargeField = Object.keys(sizedFields).find(field => 
        'max' in sizedFields[field] &&
        req.body[field].trim().length < sizedFields[field].min
    )

    if ( tooSmallField || tooLargeField) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            code: 422, 
            reason: 'Validation Error', 
            message: tooSmallField
            ? `Must be at least ${sizedFields[tooSmallField].min} characters long`
            : `Must be at most ${sizedFields[tooLargeField].max} characters long`,
            location: tooSmallField || tooLargeField
        })
    }

    // checking existance of family with same username


    return Family.find({ username })
        .count()
        .then(count => {
            if(count > 0) {
                return Promise.reject({
                    code: 422, 
                    reason: 'Validation Error', 
                    message: 'Username already taken', 
                    location: 'username'
                }); 
            }

    // creating family 

            return Family.hashPassword(password); 
        })
        .then(hash => {

        // HERE IS THE ISSUE 

            return Family.create({
                username, 
                family_name, 
                password: hash, 
                members: []
            })
        })
        .then(family => {
            return res.status(201).json(family.apiRepr()); 
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err); 
            return res.status(err.code).json({code: err.code, message: err.message, reason: err.reason, location: err.location })
        }); 
});
```

The error seems to come from the Family.create() part. But I can't figure out why... any thoughts?

I have noticed that somehow, the "id" that is initially sent in the request is somehow showing up in the DB... I've attached the record below. The $oid value is the id for the user. I do not want that to be the id for the family. How would that happen? I am not sending that information as part of Family.create()...

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a79eb5f9c36f5112e623196"
    },
    "members": [],
    "family_name": "HallissyFamily",
    "password": "$2a$10$a0XbtTonq9b0BmSi2OHIMObDQjDER/yyZxdvN58nUC93SBtrnehr2",
    "username": "something else",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: the error is saying that one of the properties is receiving value null (or not being set at all which would make mongoose set it to null), and since its giving you a duplicate error, its a field with unique: true. so if your schema has any properties with unique set to true, check to make sure that you're giving them values when creating documents. note that this field could be one that was in a previous version of your schema, even if its deleted now, if that's the case, then in your termina's mongo shell `use *dbname*` then `db.dropDatabase()` (this will erase all date in your db & reset it)

Comment: It is now magically working. That must have fixed it. Thank you

Comment: okay good because i had no idea what i could suggest next

Comment: oh by the way, i think you had a field named "parents" before but then removed it ? because that seems to be what was causing the error

Comment: You got it man! I really appreciate the help